# Share a table on Stack Overflow for easy import into MS Access

Tags: discussion

When asking MS Access questions on Stack Overflow that involve tables, how can I post the data in a format that can be easily imported into Access?

With other databases, I can simply just post multiple SQL insert statements. However, MS Access does not allow us to run multiple insert statements in this way.

If I select the records in an MS Access table and copy/paste them into stack overflow, the table turns out like this:

Table Name: `road insp`

```
INSP_ID ROAD_ID INSP_DATE   CONDITION
1   100 2009-01-01  0.1
1   100 2011-01-01  0.05
3   100 2012-01-01  0.15
4   100 2015-01-01  0.2
5   100 2017-01-01  0.25
6   200 2009-01-02  0.3
7   200 2001-01-02  0.35
8   200 2013-01-01  0.4
9   200 2017-01-01  0.45
10  300 2009-01-03  0.5
11  300 2011-01-03  0.55
12  300 2014-01-01  0.6
13  300 2015-01-01  0.65
14  300 2017-01-01  0.7
15  300 2017-12-31  0.75
16  400 2009-01-04  0.8
17  400 2011-01-04  0.85
18  400 2014-01-02  0.9
19  400 2015-01-01  0.95
20  400 2017-01-01  1
```

However, this format hardly seems useful.

1. It's hard to read.
2. It doesn't seem to import properly  to MS Access as a tab-delimited text file.

**How can I post tables on Stack Overflow for easy import into MS Access (for maximum convenience to Stack Overflow community members)?**

Comment: Here is a site with a tool to help format tables http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Comment: Mea Culpa! I fat fingered this one.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Are you sure that this is a duplicate? The answers in the suggested duplicate don't really apply to MS Access, because MS Access can't run multiple SQL statements. So multiple insert statements as DDL are not a practical option. Instead, I'm looking for an alternative option that is suited to MS Access (and it's limitations), which Andre has provided.

Comment: It's the general idea of including tables of data to support the question that I wanted to dupe to. I added another dupe, one about formatting tables.

Comment: Ok. Fair enough.

Comment: (A little late to the party...) @MartijnPieters It is possible to construct a solution specifically to run multiple SQL statements for Access: some kind of VBA harness that runs the SQL over an ADODB or DAO connection. Such a solution isn't needed for other SQL systems. Requesting a reopen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As June7 wrote: http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Copy your tab-separated data from Access (or Excel) to "Input" and click "Create".

Copy the ASCII output to the question and format as code.

```
+---------+---------+------------+-----------+
| INSP_ID | ROAD_ID | INSP_DATE  | CONDITION |
+---------+---------+------------+-----------+
|       1 |     100 | 2009-01-01 |       0.1 |
|       1 |     100 | 2011-01-01 |      0.05 |
|       3 |     100 | 2012-01-01 |      0.15 |
|       4 |     100 | 2015-01-01 |       0.2 |
|       5 |     100 | 2017-01-01 |      0.25 |
|       6 |     200 | 2009-01-02 |       0.3 |
+---------+---------+------------+-----------+
```

This is (a) nicely formatted to read, and (b) the readers can do the opposite: copy the ASCII to "Output", click "Parse", and copy the tab-separated "Input" to Access or Excel.

Comment: Wow! I didn't know that it was possible to *"do the opposite"* with that tool.

Comment: I also didn't know that it was possible to [paste tab-delimited data into an Access table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Exchange-copy-import-export-data-between-Excel-and-Access-409c27cc-c69d-461d-a74c-35392a68ed53#bmwork_with_excel_data_in_access) using `paste options` >>> `paste append`. That is handy.

Comment: For non-Access situations,  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) can be used which  has a TEXT to DDL feature.