# Post a table on Stack Overflow for easy import into MS Access

Tags: discussion

When asking MS Access questions on Stack Overflow that involve tables, how can I post the data in a format that can be easily imported into access?

With other databases, I can simply just post multiple SQL insert statements. However, MS Access does not allow us to run multiple insert statements in this way.

If I select the records in an MS Access table and copy/paste them into stack overflow, the table turns out like this:

Table Name: `road insp`

```
INSP_ID ROAD_ID INSP_DATE   CONDITION
1   100 2009-01-01  0.1
1   100 2011-01-01  0.05
3   100 2012-01-01  0.15
4   100 2015-01-01  0.2
5   100 2017-01-01  0.25
6   200 2009-01-02  0.3
7   200 2001-01-02  0.35
8   200 2013-01-01  0.4
9   200 2017-01-01  0.45
10  300 2009-01-03  0.5
11  300 2011-01-03  0.55
12  300 2014-01-01  0.6
13  300 2015-01-01  0.65
14  300 2017-01-01  0.7
15  300 2017-12-31  0.75
16  400 2009-01-04  0.8
17  400 2011-01-04  0.85
18  400 2014-01-02  0.9
19  400 2015-01-01  0.95
20  400 2017-01-01  1
```

However, this format hardly seems useful.

1. It's hard to read.
2. It doesn't seem to import properly  to MS Access as a tab-delimited text file.

**How can I post tables on Stack Overflow for easy import into MS Access (for maximum convenience to Stack Overflow community members)?**

---

*Note: For those that think this might be better suited as a **meta** question, [I've already tried that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359195/how-to-share-table-data-for-easy-import-into-ms-access), but the question was immediately deleted without much of an explanation. Without knowing the specific reason why the question was upsetting, I don't know what else to do but try posting it here.*